# Search by location using instagram API

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

I want to get the frecuency of different locations to study their popularity over time using the Instagram API. I already developed the code and my sandbox user to do so, the problem is that my "app" has not a website interface, it's just meant to be an automatic process without user interaction and I need to get "public_content" scope permissions in order to access all instagram posts. Do you believe they will approve my submission?

Comment: probably not, use a third party site that has implemented this feature, check https://www.picodash.com, it has location search